# select all columns while counting another column in a subquery

Tags: sql

I got this 2 tables for example:

| course | applied |
| --- | --- |
| id_course | id_course |
| coursename | id_student |

Course have pk (`id_course`) that also references to applied (`id_course`).

Now I would like to print ALL name from all courses and also How many are applied to them. I would like to use a subquery since with a inner join I would cut out ppl that doesn't applied (and I don't have to) but I don't know to format this subquery correctly.

```
SELECT coursename,
FROM course c 
WHERE id_course IN (SELECT id_course, COUNT(id_student)  
                    FROM iscritto i)
```

But with subquery has to be 1 row, I also tried to do the inverse subquery to try to solve this but I couldn't. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) like you were encouraged to and read the [question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Your subquery here is allowed to return any number of rows. However, it should return just the id_course column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query can be used to get the course ID, course name, and number of students that applied to the course.

```
SELECT c.id_course, c.coursename, count(a.id_course) as count_of_students_applied
FROM course c left join applied a
ON c.id_course=a.id_course
GROUP BY c.id_course, a.id_course, c.coursename
ORDER BY count_of_students_applied desc, c.id_course
```

You can also write queries in different ways to get the same result.